# What is the probability density function of $X_1+X_2$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution, density-function

Given $X_1 \sim \exp(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim  \exp(\lambda_2)$, and that they are independent, how can I calculate the probability density function of $X_1+X_2$?

---

I tried to define $Z=X_1+X_2$ and then:  $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Z,X_1}(z,x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty f_{Z,X_1}(z,x) \, dx$.
And I don't know how to continue from this point.

Comment: You cannot, unless it is given also that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. In that case you can apply [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). Try that out and if you get stuck then edit your question, add your efforts and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: @drhab I did that, than you.

Comment: @drhab : It is somewhat exaggerated to say this can be done only when they are independent. But certainly one needs at least some information about their joint distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's right. "More info needed" is more appropriate. My words were inspired by the fact that **a.s.** the OP had forgotten to mention that the rv's were independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_Z(z)=\int f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(z-x)dx$$

Note that in your case the RHS has integrand $0$ if $z\leq0$ so that $f_Z(z)=0$ if $z\leq0$.

For $z>0$ we have:$$f_Z(z)=\int f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(z-x)dx=\int_0^{z}f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(z-x)dx$$

Work this out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Assuming independence.

We are given that the P.D.F. of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\, x\ge0$ and the P.D.F. of $Y$ is $f_Y(Y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y},\, y\ge0$.

Then using convolution, $$\begin{align}f_{X+Y}(x+y)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x+y-y)f_Y(y)\,dy\\&=\int_0^{x+y}\lambda e^{-\lambda(x+y)}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,dy\end{align}$$ which should now to easy to integrate.

Comment: Can you explain how to integrate that?

Comment: Further hint: take the $\lambda$s outside of the integral and use the exponential rule to combine the $\exp$ terms. Since we are integrating over $y$, treat $x$ as a constant.

Comment: But $y$ in the upper limit of the integral

Comment: So? Just integrate it w.r.t. $y$ and then substitute $x+y$ and $0$ into the integrated expression respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Just as has been pointed out by the other answers, you can simply calculate the pdf for $X_1 + X_2$ by using the principle of *convolution*. In fact, in general one can show that if $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ are i.i.d variables with exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then $S = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \sim \Gamma (n,\lambda)$.